# How to distinguish android devices in Low/Mid/High?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I just got stuck in differentiating various android devices into low/medium/high settings.

I want to apply game quality accordingly.

is there any way to derives this??

i am using Unity3D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this image :
 [image]

There is also xxhdpi which is around 480 ppi.

From : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
You can also see how many devices use these configuration here : http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens

Comment: Your answer is missing actual code which shows the asker how to determine the device resolution programmatically.

Comment: yes, if you could help with some code reference then it will be gr8. BDW thanks Stephane for your help

Comment: I never used Unity3D, but I just saw this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/391178/high-res-icons-for-android-builds-.html and it seams that you can use the default Android behavior to manage different resources. Do you have a drawable folder somewhere in your project ? Just create a drawable-hdpi or drawable-xxhpi and so on.